# Implementing Audit Log / Change History with MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, audit

I am building in a Change History / Audit Log to my MVC app which is using the Entity Framework.

So specifically in the edit method `public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel vm)`, we find the object we are trying to update, and then use `TryUpdateModel(object)` to transpose the values from the form on to the object that we are trying to update.

I want to log a change when any field of that object changes. So basically what I need is a copy of the object before it is edited and then compare it after the `TryUpdateModel(object)` has done its work. i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel vm)
{
    //Need to take the copy here
    var object = EntityFramework.Object.Single(x=>x.ID = vm.ID);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Form the un edited view model
        var uneditedVM = BuildViewModel(vm.ID); //this line seems to confuse the EntityFramework (BuildViewModel() is used to build the model when originally displaying the form)
        //Compare with old view model
        WriteChanges(uneditedVM, vm);
        ...
        TryUpdateModel(object);
    }
    ...
}
```

But the problem is when the code retrieves the "unedited vm", this is causing some unexpected  changes in the EntityFramework - so that `TryUpdateModel(object);` throws an `UpdateException`.

**So the question is** - in this situation - how do I create a copy of the `object` outside of EntityFramework to compare for change/audit history, so that it does not affect or change the 
EntityFramework at all

edit: Do not want to use triggers. Need to log the username who did it.

edit1: Using EFv4, not too sure how to go about overriding `SaveChanges()` but it may be an option

---

This route seems to be going nowhere, for such a simple requirement! I finally got it to override properly, but now I get an exception with that code:

```
public partial class Entities
{
    public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    {
        DetectChanges();
        var modifiedEntities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var modifiedProps = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry).GetModifiedProperties(); //This line throws exception The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry'.
            var currentValues = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry).CurrentValues;
            foreach (var propName in modifiedProps)
            {
                var newValue = currentValues[propName];
                //log changes
            }
        }

        //return base.SaveChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/puygwzyb

Comment: Or... you dont create!... just get this nuget package instead. http://www.nuget.org/packages/trackerenableddbcontext

Comment: @Rosdi Yeh that'll solve the problem by adding a ton more bloat to your solution when this problem can be solved with very little code. I don't get why people feel the need to pull in packages for literally everything lately instead of just writing a few lines.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IF you are using EF 4 you can subscribe to the `SavingChanges` event.

Since `Entities` is a partial class you can add additional functionality in a separate file. So create a new file named `Entities` and there implement the partial method `OnContextCreated` to hook up the event

```
public partial class Entities
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        SavingChanges += OnSavingChanges;
    }

    void OnSavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var modifiedEntities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var modifiedProps = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).GetModifiedProperties();
            var currentValues = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).CurrentValues;
            foreach (var propName in modifiedProps)
            {
                var newValue = currentValues[propName];
                //log changes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using EF 4.1 you can go through [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx) to extract changes

Comment: "There is no suitable method for override" ?

Comment: @baron you can handle the [SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event

Comment: Also "base class ObjectContext doesn't contain parameterless constructor". Did you have a blog where you got that code from ?

Comment: I really don't understand how to set this up. I create a class "Test" which extends `ObjectContext` do I set up the event handler in this class ?

Comment: @baron no you don't need to create a separate "Test" which extends `ObjectContext`. instead you need to subscribe in your `Entities` constructor. I have edited my answer

Comment: @Eranga, keep in mind that the Entities is auto-generated, it's better that he create a new class that inherits from the generated context than to edit the generated code.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. Thank you Omar. Although I tried the code you provided, when I perform `Entities.SaveChanges();` and have breakpoint on the `context_SavingChanges()` method - it never enters!

Answer (score 15):

See [FrameLog](https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/framelog/wiki/Home), an Entity Framework logging library that I wrote for this purpose. It is open-source, including for commercial use.

I know that you would rather just see a code snippet showing how to do this, but to properly handle all the cases for logging, including relationship changes and many-to-many changes, the code gets quite large. Hopefully the library will be a good fit for your needs, but if not you can freely adapt the code.

FrameLog can log changes to all scalar and navigation properties, and also allows you to specify a subset that you are interested in logging.

Comment: I've implemented FrameLog in my project and it's working fine with only a few hours work doing the integration. I'm using it now for a single table in my database that I needed to create an audit log for.

Comment: It's a real nice framework. Very easy to use and customize. In less than 3 hours we have implemented this on our project. Thank you. You did a good job Martin =)

Comment: Anyone looking for a simple audit log, there is one here: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended  Otherwise FrameLog rocks

Comment: Here is another one: [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

There is an article with high rating here at the codeproject: [Implementing Audit Trail using Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34491/Implementing-Audit-Trail-using-Entity-Framework-Pa) . It seems to do what you want. I have started to use this solution in a project. I first wrote triggers in T-SQL in the database but it was too hard to maintain them with changes in the object model happening all the time.