# How to logging data change with Entity Framework, otherwise how to do it with SQL Server 2008 Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, logging, entity-framework-4

I use SQL Server 2008 Standard, Asp.net MVC 2 and Entity Framework 4.0

I would like to know the best and simplest way to log data change. I read a little bit about change data capture and seem to be very interesting.

I just wanted to know if I can log directly with Entity Framework. I have a total of 170 entities. If possible, is there a generic method to perform my needs ?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Take a look at [Implementing Audit Log / Change History with Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867459/implementing-audit-log-change-history-with-mvc-entity-framework/6867622#6867622)