# Creating an Audit Trail in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I had a shot at the method that overrides SaveChanges described here:
http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2011/07/26/auditing-with-entity-framework.aspx

Managed to implement it but the records are not getting written to the database.

Has anyone tried this? If not, are there any other guides out there that are specific to MVC? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Audit Log / Change History with MVC & Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867459/implementing-audit-log-change-history-with-mvc-entity-framework)

Comment: Just read it a minute ago and realized I may have posted a question too soon.

Comment: which framework - 4 or 5?