# How to populate complex types as soon as the entity is inserted/modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this `Complex Type` included in my entity class, such as:

```
public class Logbook
{
  public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
  public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

Then my main class:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Logbook Logbook { get; set; }
}
```

I then set class `Logbook` as a complex type. My question is, I'm wondering on how to set the values in `Logbook` as soon as `Customer` entity is inserted/modified? Say, set the `DateCreated` to `DateTime.UtcNow` and set `CreatedBy` to a user's name.. And so on. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using `Entity Framework` for my data access. And this is how I save my `Customer`

```
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
  if ( Model.IsValid() )
  {
    _customerRepository.Insert(customer);
    return View("Index");
  }

  return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create a new `Customer`?

Comment: Before or after you save `Customer`?

Comment: What do you mean by insert/update? Entity framework? Do you use repository or something?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867459/implementing-audit-log-change-history-with-mvc-entity-framework

Comment: ps. lots of other interesting articles about on this: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc%20audit%20fields%20pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not konw if it possible to do it automatically. In my case I've prepared a special,  generic method that handles entity update in log (it's IoC frendly in every case :) ):

```
public T PrepareLogbookProperty<T>(T model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }

    var dynamicModel = (dynamic)model;

    Entity value;

    try
    {
        value = dynamicModel.Logbook as Logbook;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        throw new NoLogbookPropertyFound();
    }

    value = this.PassLog(value); // THAT METHOD PASSES CURRENT USER OR DATE TIME.

    dynamicModel.Logbook= value;

    return model;
}
```

It has one drawback - it's unfortunately dynamic. In order to handle other cases, I've preprared other overloaded function:

```
public TEntity PrepareLogbookProperty<TEntity>(TEntity model, Expression<Func<TEntity, Logbook>> entityExpression)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }

    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)entityExpression.Body;
    var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

    var value = property.GetValue(model) as Logbook;
    value = this.PassLog(value);

    property.SetValue(model, value);

    return model;
}
```

Usage:

```
this.helper.PrepareLogbookProperty(customer, cust => custom.MyOtherLogBook); // expression version
```

or

```
this.helper.PrepareLogbookProperty(product); // dynamic version (I assume that product has Logbook property
```

Method is called manually before every `SaveChanges()`.

Unfortuantely, I couldn't change DB schema and the way that it was designed - so that solution was suitable for me.

Sample pass log:

```
private Logbook PassLog(Logbook entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        entity = this.NewLogbook();
    }

    entity.EditedDate = this.dateTimeProvider.Now;
    entity.EditorID = this.services.CurrentUser.ID;

    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?

```
public class Logbook
{
  public Logbook(string username)
  {
    this.CreatedBy = username;
    this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow; //NB: ideally your database would provide this to ensure if deployed on multiple servers you'd have one date source
    this.ModifiedBy = username;
    this.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow; //as above
  }
  public void Modify(string username)
  {
    this.ModifiedBy = username;
    this.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow; //as above
  }
  public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
  public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
  private int id;
  public int Id { 
    get { return this.id; } 
    set { this.id = value; this.OnCreateOrModify(); }
  }

  private string name;
  public string Name { 
    get { return this.name; }
    set { this.name = value; this.OnCreateOrModify(); }
  }
  public Logbook Logbook { get; private set; } //presumably you don't want other classes to amend this
  private void OnCreateOrModify()
  {
    var username = System.Environment.UserName;  //or pass something into your class contructor to provide a username
    if (this.Logbook == null) //create
        this.Logbook = new LogBook(username);
    else //modify
        this.Logbook.Modify(username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm and what about Database First? Every model update from DB I'd to manually edit generated entity classes what is not recommended I suppose.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But can you explain this line? `set { this.id = value; this,OnCreateOrModify(); }`

Comment: @BoyPasmo typo; the comma should have been a dot.  This assigns a value to a property (in this case id) and ensures that the related audit entries are updated accordingly.

Comment: @pwas not sure tbh; EF's pretty new to me, so basing my answer on what I did in pre-EF days.