# Entity Framework 6 (code first) entity versioning and auditing

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm looking at using Entity Framework 6.1.1 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Currently I'm creating my models and database using the code-first EF feature. My basic use-case is to create a journal of all changes to a particular entity (`ID` is the key column) to help auditors track all changes made and by whom. e.g:

```
|ID|Version|Created Date|Created By|Modified Date|Modified By|Modify Action| ... (rest of entity fields)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4| 12    | 12-Mar-14  | tom      | 20-Feb-15   | jack      | Update      |
| 4| 11    | 12-Mar-14  | tom      | 14-Feb-15   | jill      | Update      |
| 4| 1     | 12-Mar-14  | tom      | 12-Mar-14   | tom       | Create      |
```

Does Entity Framework support this type of database scheme? If so, how can I set my models/solution up to facilitate this?

The other alternative I have is by intercepting all calls to the `SaveChanges()` method on the `DbContext` and log all database changes into a separate `Audit` table, but this might make retrieving information more challenging.

Any help on creating audit trails with SQL Server and EF 6 would be greately appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Audit Log / Change History with MVC & Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867459/implementing-audit-log-change-history-with-mvc-entity-framework)

Comment: This can possibly get you on your way: http://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/

Comment: I was rather hoping to have entity versions as this is consistent with other database applications. Currently versioning is managed by monster T-SQL functions which I have no desire to implement, especially with EF!

Answer (score 7):

I have used the 2nd approach you mention, by overloading the dbContext SaveChanges() method:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

 public int SaveChanges(int userId)
 {
    // Get all Added/Deleted/Modified entities (not Unmodified or Detached)
    foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State ==  EntityState.Added 
    || p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {

        foreach (AuditLog x in GetAuditRecordsForChange(ent, userId))
        {
            this.AuditLogs.Add(x);
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
  }
...
```

So if I want to log a particular entity, I just call the overloaded SaveChanges & pass in a UserId:

```
public void Update(StockCatalogueItem entity, int userId)
{
     _context.SaveChanges(userId);
}
```

I also have a custom `DoNotLog` attribute which I use to decorate the entity properties that I don't want to log.  Without this, the logging could generate a huge amount of data, as each entity modification equals one db entry.

```
[DoNotLog]
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

The `GetAuditRecordsForChange` method does the checking for any `DoNotLog` properties and returns a `List<AuditLog>` which gets saved in the AuditLogs table:

```
public class AuditLog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public AuditEventType EventType { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [Entity Framework Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log). It has audit functionality that I have used to log all changes to entities to XML. From the documentation:

> The Audit Log feature will capture the changes to entities anytime
>   they are submitted to the database. The Audit Log captures only the
>   entities that are changed and only the properties on those entities
>   that were changed. The before and after values are recorded.
>   AuditLogger.LastAudit is where this information is held and there is a
>   ToXml() method that makes it easy to turn the AuditLog into xml for
>   easy storage.
>
> The AuditLog can be customized via attributes on the entities or via a
>   Fluent Configuration API.

**UPDATE:**

Entity Framework Extended is no longer supported since 2015.
Please refer to [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended) for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a good candidate for the event sourcing pattern mentioned in a DDD architecture. You never change your entity table but always inserting.

In that way, when you need an specific version you just re-play all events and apply them to the entity from version 0 to the version you are looking for. Scalability can be solved with entity snapshots.

Second approach is also valid.

Reference:
http://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html